# Tornado websocket blob object

Tags: jquery, blob, tornado

My current code is supposed to send data to a server from a website which will send the message back to the website and print it out. I'm using JQuery for the website and Tornado for the Server. My Current code successfully sends text to the server but receives a blob object when the server sends the text back.

```
   function setup() {
       var host = "ws://localhost:8889/"; 
       var socket = new WebSocket(host);  
       var $txt = $("#inputField");       // the text field in the html
       var $btnSend = $("#pingButton");   // the send button in the html
       $txt.focus();
       // receiving message - issue is here
       socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
           var newmessage = msg;  // replace newmessage with msg when issue fixed
           console.log(newmessage); // shows content of blobobject
           // $("#messageText").text(newmessage.data+pingcount);
           alert(newmessage.data + pingcount);
           pingcount++;             // pingcount is to show stuff is happening
           // alert(newmessage.data);
       }
       $btnSend.on('click', function() {
                   var text = $txt.val();
                   if (text == "") {
                       return;
                   }
                   socket.send(text);
                   $txt.val("");
       });
       $txt.keypress(function(evt) {
                 if (evt.which == 13) {
                     $btnSend.click();
                 }
       });
       // event handlers for websocket
       // anything below this point seems fine
       if (socket) {
           socket.onopen = function() {
               // alert("connection opened....");
           }
           socket.onclose = function() {
               alert("connection closed....");
           }
       } else {
           console.log("invalid socket");
       }
   }
```

My Tornado Server

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
from tornado.websocket import WebSocketHandler
from tornado.options import define, options, parse_command_line

define("port", default=8889, help="run on the given port", type=int)
#link - http://localhost:8889/
#experimental websocket
class EchoWebSocket(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True
    def open(self):
        print ("WebSocket opened")

    def on_message(self, message):

        self.write_message("You said: " , message)
        print("message received",message)

    def on_close(self):
        print("WebSocket closed")
app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/', EchoWebSocket),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_command_line()
    app.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution
write_message needed another argument

```
def on_message(self, message):
    Letter="You said:"+message
    self.write_message(Letter,False)
    print("message recieved",message)
```